# How to use array_contains in hive

Tags: hive

I have a hive query like

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE array_contains(['2019-05-17','2019-04-20'],date)
```

and I keep getting an error saying

```
cannot recognize near '['
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `array` should be constructed as `array(1,2,3)`; not as `[1,2,3]` like some programming languages. Use

```
array_contains(array('2019-05-17','2019-04-20'),val)
```

Note that the second argument to `array_contains` should be a scalar value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget the `= True`

```
SELECT * FROM table_a 

WHERE array_contains(['2019-05-17','2019-04-20'], date) = True
```